# Magento-2 show calendar to chose date

Tags: magento-2.1, forms, calendar

I have a popup form with DOB field. I would like to get Calendar shown when a customer clicks on DOB text field or on click on calendar icon beside DOB field.
My HTML is:

```
<div class="field date field-dob required">
                <label class="label" for="dob"><span>Date of Birth</span></label>
                <div class="control customer-dob">
                    <input type="text" name="dob" id="customer_dob" value="" class="_has-datepicker" data-validate="{required:true}" autocomplete="off" aria-required="true" /><button type="button" class="ui-datepicker-trigger v-middle"><span>Select Date</span></button>
                    <script>
                        require([
                            "jquery",
                            "mage/calendar"
                        ], function($){
                            $("#customer_dob").calendar({
                                buttonText:"<?php echo __('Select Date') ?>",
                            });
                        });
                    </script>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image: Screen-shot]

Comment: what you getting in console log using this script?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Dhaval I don't get any errors in the console or any logs neither.

Comment: @SachinAgarwal, can you please check console log click on your textbox.
may be error generate click on

Comment: @Dhaval, No I can't see any error in Console log

Comment: @NikunjVadariya, There is no error is being logged in console and log file neither.